# general topology exercise

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $\mathbb R^n$ with the usual metric. Let $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open set and $K \subset U$ a compact set. 
Is the following affirmation true?

> There exists an open set $U^{'}$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with $\overline{U^{'}} \subset U $ and $K \subset U^{'}$ "

Can someone please give me some help?

I believe that the affirmation is true...

Comment: Actually your condition that $K$ be compact is stronger than necessary. Perhaps it will help you to think about weakening it.

Comment: If you happen to know that $\Bbb R^n$ is a normal Hausdorff space, you could weaken the assumption to $K$ being closed. That may not be something the OP is familiar with, though.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to tag @dfeuer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x\in K$, we have $x\in U$, so since $U$ is open, then there exists $r_x>0$ such that the open ball about $x$ of radius $r_x$ is a subset of $U$. Then the ball about $x$ of radius $\frac{r_x}2$ is certainly a subset of $U$, as is its closure. We can cover $K$ by a set of the latter sort of open ball--in fact, by finitely-many of them, since $K$ is compact. Let $U'$ be the union of that finite collection of open balls, so $U'$ is an open set, and $U'\supseteq K$. Since the closure of a finite union is the union of the closures, and since the closure of each of the open balls is contained in $U$, then $\overline{U'}\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $K$ is compact, the distance from $K$ to $R^n \setminus U$ is a positive number, say $d$.

Then take a neighborhood ball with radius $d/2$ of each point of $K$.

Let $U'$ be the union of these balls. It satisfies $K \subset \bar U' \subset U$.

Comment: Do you mean the distance from $K$ to $\mathbb R^n \setminus U$?

Comment: @dfeuer You are right. Thanks. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb R^n$ is a Hausdorff space and $K$ is a compact subspace thereof. Thus $K$ is closed in $\mathbb R^n$.

Since $\mathbb R^n$ is also a normal space, your result follows.